# How do you use Presentation Model with Winforms?

Tags: .net, winforms, design-patterns

Would Like to know how best to implement the Presentation Model pattern. I have read about MVVM but does not apply to me as I'm not using Silverlight or WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Update Controls](http://updatecontrols.net/cs/winforms.shtml) implements the Presentation Model pattern in Windows Forms. You write a model class using Independent fields.

```
public class Person
{
    private Independent<string> _first = new Independent<string>();
    private Independent<string> _last = new Independent<string>();

    public string First
    {
        get { return _first; }
        set { _first.Value = value; }
    }

    public string Last
    {
        get { return _last; }
        set { _last.Value = value; }
    }
}
```

Then you write a presentation model with regular properties.

```
public class PersonPresentationModel
{
    private Person _person;

    public PersonPresentationModel(Person person)
    {
        _person = person;
    }

    public Person Person
    {
        get { return _person; }
    }

    public string FullName
    {
        get { return _person.Last + ", " + _person.First; }
    }
}
```

Handle events in your Windows Forms controls to get data from the presentation model.

```
    private string FirstName_GetText()
    {
        return _presentationModel.Person.First;
    }

    private void FirstName_SetText(string value)
    {
        _presentationModel.Person.First = value;
    }

    private string LastName_GetText()
    {
        return _presentationModel.Person.Last;
    }

    private void LastName_SetText(string value)
    {
        _presentationModel.Person.Last = value;
    }

    private string FullName_GetText()
    {
        return _presentationModel.FullName;
    }
```

Update Controls will track the dependencies and update your Windows Forms controls when the model changes. It will even peer through the presentation model to see what it depends upon.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interrested by [MVP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-presenter) (Model View Presenter), and rich application frameworks that rely on it, like [CAB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480450.aspx) (Composite UI Application Block, from MS Pattern & Practice team)

Using MVP, you can have a presentation model and leverage winform databinding.

[Jeremy D. Miller blog](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2007/07/25/the-build-your-own-cab-series-table-of-contents.aspx) is a good source of information regarding this design, and all other UI patterns.